# Alternative of CancellationToken.Register for async methods / on BackgroundService closing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm looking for an alternative of `stoppingToken.Register(ShutDown)` where I'm able to call async methods? Basically, `_restClient.Spot.UserStream.StopUserStreamAsync` should be awaited. Right now it isn't.

Any other suggestions are appreciated.

```cs
using Binance.Net;
using Binance.Net.Enums;
using Binance.Net.Interfaces;
using Binance.Net.Objects;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Authentication;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Objects;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Sockets;

namespace QSGEngine.Server.Services
{
    public class PortfolioService : BackgroundService
    {
        private const string ApiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        private const string SecretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        private readonly ILogger<PortfolioService> _logger;
        private readonly IBinanceClient _restClient;
        private readonly IBinanceSocketClient _socketClient;

        public PortfolioService(ILogger<PortfolioService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            _restClient = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions
            {
                ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(ApiKey, SecretKey),
                AutoTimestamp = true,
                AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                TradeRulesBehaviour = TradeRulesBehaviour.AutoComply,
#if DEBUG
                LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug,
                LogWriters = new List<ILogger> { _logger } // TODO: FIX
#endif
            });

            _socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions
            {
                ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(ApiKey, SecretKey),
                AutoReconnect = true,
                ReconnectInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
#if DEBUG
                LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug,
                LogWriters = new List<ILogger> { _logger } // TODO: FIX
#endif
            });
        }

        private string? _listenKey;
        private CallResult<UpdateSubscription>? _userDataUpdateSubscription;
        
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            stoppingToken.Register(ShutDown);
            
            // Create listen key
            var listenKeyResult = await _restClient.Spot.UserStream.StartUserStreamAsync(stoppingToken);
            
            if (!listenKeyResult.Success)
            {
                return;
            }

            _listenKey = listenKeyResult.Data;

            // Subscribe to web socket
            _userDataUpdateSubscription = await _socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToUserDataUpdatesAsync(_listenKey,
                null,
                null,
                data =>
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("ASD {Balances}", data.Data.Balances);
                },
                data =>
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("BALANCE DELTA {BalanceDelta}", data.Data.BalanceDelta);
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (!_userDataUpdateSubscription.Success)
            {
                return;
            }
            
            _userDataUpdateSubscription.Data.Exception += PortfolioService_Exception;
            
            // Keep the listen key alive
            using var keepAlive = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // Listen key will be alive for 60 minutes
                    await _restClient.Spot.UserStream.KeepAliveUserStreamAsync(_listenKey, stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50), stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }, stoppingToken);
        }

        private void ShutDown()
        {
            // Unsubscribe from Exception event
            if (_userDataUpdateSubscription != null)
            {
                _userDataUpdateSubscription.Data.Exception -= PortfolioService_Exception;
                _userDataUpdateSubscription = null;
            }

            // Stop listen key
            if (_listenKey != null)
            {
                _restClient.Spot.UserStream.StopUserStreamAsync(_listenKey).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                _listenKey = null;
            }
        }

        private void PortfolioService_Exception(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Exception: {StackTrace}", ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Wrap your shutdown logic in an `IAsyncDisposable`. You can either write your own implementation or use an anonymous disposable like `AsyncDisposable` from my `Nito.Disposables` library.
2. Use an `await using` declaration to asynchronously wait for the disposal.

When the background service is shut down, it will raise an `OperationCanceledException`. The `await using` will ensure the disposal asynchronously completes before propagating that exception.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  // Create listen key
  var listenKeyResult = await _restClient.Spot.UserStream.StartUserStreamAsync(stoppingToken);
  if (!listenKeyResult.Success)
    return;

  _listenKey = listenKeyResult.Data;
  await using var disposeListenKey = new AsyncDisposable(async () => await _restClient.Spot.UserStream.StopUserStreamAsync(_listenKey));

  // Subscribe to web socket
  _userDataUpdateSubscription = await _socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToUserDataUpdatesAsync(_listenKey,
      null,
      null,
      data =>
      {
        _logger.LogInformation("ASD {Balances}", data.Data.Balances);
      },
      data =>
      {
        _logger.LogInformation("BALANCE DELTA {BalanceDelta}", data.Data.BalanceDelta);
      }).ConfigureAwait(false);
  if (!_userDataUpdateSubscription.Success)
    return;
            
  _userDataUpdateSubscription.Data.Exception += PortfolioService_Exception;
  using var disposeExceptionHandler = new Disposable(() =>
      _userDataUpdateSubscription.Data.Exception -= PortfolioService_Exception);
            
  // Keep the listen key alive
  using var keepAlive = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    while (true)
    {
      // Listen key will be alive for 60 minutes
      await _restClient.Spot.UserStream.KeepAliveUserStreamAsync(_listenKey, stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50), stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
  }, stoppingToken);
}
```

Comment: By the way, I forgot that `_restClient` and `_socketClient` should also be disposed. How do I that in the current BackgroundService?

Comment: Just like: `using var disposeRestClient = new Disposable(() => _restClient.Dispose());` and `using var disposeSocketClient = new Disposable(() => _socketClient.Dispose());`? https://pastebin.com/srnwaFNb

Comment: @nop: If they're already disposable, then you shouldn't need a separate wrapper. `using var disposeRestClient = _restClient` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, if I leave these in the constructor, then I'm receiving `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SecureString'.'`. Is it okay to put them into the destructor `~PortfolioService() { using var disposeRestClient = _restClient; using var disposeSocketClient = _socketClient; }` ?

Comment: @nop They should not go in either the constructor or destructor. Either put the `using var` in the `ExecuteAsync` method or implement `IDisposable` and call `Dispose` from your `Dispose` implementation.